# Casting from Object to Enum

Tags: java, arrays, generics

So I'm trying to implement a CircularBuffer in `Java`, to which I can access the underlying `array`:

```
/* package protected */ class CircularBuffer<E> {
private final Object[] mArray;
private int mSize;
private int headPointer = 0;

private CircularBuffer(int size) {
  mSize = size;
  mArray = new Object[mSize];
}

private void add(E elem) {
  mArray[headPointer] = elem;
  headPointer = (headPointer + 1) % mSize;
}

public E[] getArray() {
  return (E[]) this.mArray;
}
```

}

I want to use this with `Enums` and various primitives (specifically `boolean`s), but everything I call `myEnum[] = myCircularBuffer.getArray()`, I get a:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to com.package.myEnum[]
```

Any tips on making something like this work?

Edit: I do know about the Apache CircularFifoQueue, but I don't want to use it since its way more than I need and I'm concerned about package size.

Comment: you cannot cast Object[] to myEnums straight away! Unless you make sure your mArray accepts type of objects that are either myEnum type or subclasses... Use generics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make your internal `mArray` an array of the generic type `E` and not an array of `Object`. In order to do this you have to change your constructor to also get the `Class` of your generic `E` type. And also declare your mArray to be of type `E[]` which will help you to avoid further unneccessary casts (e.g. your `getArray()` method can simply return `mArray` without casting).

You can do that like this:

```
private final E[] mArray;

private CircularBuffer(int size, Class<E> type) {
    mSize = size;
    mArray = (E[]) Array.newInstance(type, size);
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
CircularBuffer<String> buff = new CircularBuffer<>(10, String.class);
String[] arr = buff.getArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array whose runtime type is `Object[]`. It cannot possibly be `E[]` because arrays know their component type at runtime, and your class can't possibly know what `E` is, because it has no knowledge of it at runtime.

Imagine that if you could do it, then `new CircularBuffer<E>(size).getArray()` would be a backdoor way of doing `new E[size]`, which is not possible in Java.

You can look at what the `List` interface in the Java standard library does. It also does not know the generic argument at runtime. It has two `toArray` methods: 1) one with no arguments that returns type `Object[]`, and 2) one that takes a `T[]` argument and returns a `T[]`. The second one needs an array passed in to get the type `T` to construct the result array.